# How to reverse a hana::string

Tags: c++, templates, boost-hana

Does anyone know how to reverse a boost::hana::string?

The following does not work:

```cpp
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/reverse.hpp>
auto s = BOOST_HANA_STRING("abc");
auto s2 = boost::hana::reverse(s);
```

with the error message:

```cpp
boost/hana/reverse.hpp:36:9: error: static_assert failed due to requirement 
'hana::Sequence<S>::value' "hana::reverse(xs) 
 requires 'xs' to be a Sequence"
```

The [hana string doc](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/hana/doc/html/structboost_1_1hana_1_1string.html) says :

> In particular, one should not take for granted that the template parameters are chars. The proper way to access the contents of a hana::string as character constants is to use hana::unpack, .c_str() or hana::to

So, I guess the direction where to look is "how to transform a hana::string to a [Sequence](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/hana/doc/html/group__group-Sequence.html)"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost.Hana is certainly functional, but if you can avoid folding on types you can get a more compile-time efficient algorithm.

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

template <typename S, unsigned long ...i>
auto reverse_string_impl(S s, std::index_sequence<i...>) {
  constexpr unsigned long n = sizeof...(i);
  constexpr char const* c = hana::to<char const*>(s);
  return hana::make_string(hana::char_c<c[n - i - 1]>...);
  // would be better but assumes stuff about the impl of hana::string
  //return hana::string<c[n - i - 1]...>{};
}

template <typename S>
constexpr auto reverse_string(S) {
  return reverse_string_impl(S{},
    std::make_index_sequence<hana::length(S{})>{});
}

int main() {
  BOOST_HANA_CONSTANT_ASSERT(
      BOOST_HANA_STRING("foo") == reverse_string(BOOST_HANA_STRING("oof"))
  );

  // or just convert to a tuple and back (less efficient)
  BOOST_HANA_CONSTANT_ASSERT(
      BOOST_HANA_STRING("foo") ==
        hana::unpack(
          hana::reverse(hana::unpack(BOOST_HANA_STRING("oof"),
                        hana::make_tuple)),
          hana::make_string)


  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hum, I had to dig a little into the internals of a hana string.

But Hana is deliciously functional, so that this short solution is enough:

```cpp
auto reverse_boost_hana_string = [](auto s) {
    auto add_reverse = [=](auto xs, auto ys) {
        auto ys_s = boost::hana::string<ys>(); // this is what I had wrong for a while
        return ys_s + xs;
    };
    auto reversed = boost::hana::fold_left(s, BOOST_HANA_STRING(""), add_reverse);
    return reversed;
};


int main()
{
    auto s = BOOST_HANA_STRING("abcdef");
    auto s2 = reverse_boost_hana_string(s);
    std::cout << "Reversed ==>" <<  s2.c_str() << "<==\n";
}
```

It is seriously pleasing to write TMP without the template noise.